# If $z$ is any complex number, then the area of the triangle formed by the complex numbers $z$, $wz$, $z+wz$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z$ is any complex number, then the area of the triangle formed by the complex numbers $z$, $wz$, $z+wz$ as its sides is?

I solved a similar question where the triangle was formed by three complex numbers as vertices. How will we solve when they are represented as sides?

Comment: Is w cube root of unity ?

Comment: Yes it is a cube root of unity

Comment: @user42172 You must specify that $w$ is a ***complex*** cube root of unity, since $w=1$ is also a cube root of unity, but in that case the area is $0\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the triangle formed is isosceles, as $$|z| = |\omega z|$$
Now, $$\cos \theta = \frac{|z|^2 + |\omega z|^2 -|z+z\omega|^2}{2|z||\omega z|} = \frac{2 - |1+\omega|^2}{2} = 1 - \frac{|1+\omega|^2}{2}$$

Area of triangle is given by,
$$A=|z|^2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{2}|z|^2\sin \theta$$

**EDIT**

We can further reduce $|1+\omega| = |1+\frac{-1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}| = |\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}| = 1$

Hence, the triange is equilateral, with side $|z|$

Comment: The triangle is equilateral as per the solution of book

Comment: That will actually come out to be the case, as $|1+\omega|$ = 1

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan $|1+w|=1$ also follows from $1+w+w^2=0$ when $w$ is a complex cube root of unity.